# Как перевернуть строку в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется строка 123456, надо перевернуть ее чтобы она стала 654321.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться отрицательным шагом слайса

```
'123456'[::-1]
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/lBm9Zr

Comment: Вот чем мне нравится Питон - тем, что он лаконичен, и в нём продуманы такие фичи

Comment: это идиоматичный способ для строк: краток, эффективен и ясен людям знакомым с Питоном

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так через reversed:

```
def reverse(input): 
    return ''.join(reversed(input))
```

Вот так с lambda:

```
def reverse(input):
     return reduce(lambda x,y : y+x, input)
```

И еще вот так с рекурсией для полноты картины:

```
def reverse(input): 
    if len(s) == 1:
        return input
    return input[-1] + reverse(input[:-1])
```